# Keep tags order using SnakeYAML

Tags: json, yaml, snakeyaml

I'm trying to translate yaml files to json, but the translation re-orders the tags...
Ex, YAML source:

```
zzzz:
  b: 456
  a: dfff
aa:
  s10: "dddz"
  s3: eeee
bbb:
 - b1
 - a2
```

snakeYAML produces:

```
{
  "aa": {
    "s3": "eeee",
    "s10":"dddz"
  },
  "bbb":[
    "b1",
    "a2"
  ],
  "zzzz": {
    "a": "dfff",
    "b":456
  }
}
```

Comment: In YAML maps are unordered, that's why your translation re-order tags. For preserve tags ordering you need to use low-level YAML parsing, which allows you to reimplement token's processing. Probably, this will help: https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#Low_Level_API.

Comment: SnakeYAML's code and documentation keeps moving, see [the Bitbucket site for the Low Level API](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-low-level-api).

Answer (score 4):

Create following class in your code, this is a tweaked version from the SnakeYAML source that uses `LinkedHashMap` and `LinkedHashSet` that keep the insertion order instead of `TreeMap` and `TreeSet` which auto-sort them.

```java
    import java.beans.FeatureDescriptor;
    import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
    import java.beans.Introspector;
    import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
    import java.lang.reflect.Field;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
    import java.util.*;
    
    import org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException;
    import org.yaml.snakeyaml.introspector.*;
    import org.yaml.snakeyaml.util.PlatformFeatureDetector;
    
    public class CustomPropertyUtils extends PropertyUtils {
    
        private final Map<Class<?>, Map<String, Property>> propertiesCache = new HashMap<Class<?>, Map<String, Property>>();
        private final Map<Class<?>, Set<Property>> readableProperties = new HashMap<Class<?>, Set<Property>>();
        private BeanAccess beanAccess = BeanAccess.DEFAULT;
        private boolean allowReadOnlyProperties = false;
        private boolean skipMissingProperties = false;
    
        private PlatformFeatureDetector platformFeatureDetector;
    
        public CustomPropertyUtils() {
            this(new PlatformFeatureDetector());
        }
    
        CustomPropertyUtils(PlatformFeatureDetector platformFeatureDetector) {
            this.platformFeatureDetector = platformFeatureDetector;
    
            /*
             * Android lacks much of java.beans (including the Introspector class, used here), because java.beans classes tend to rely on java.awt, which isn't
             * supported in the Android SDK. That means we have to fall back on FIELD access only when SnakeYAML is running on the Android Runtime.
             */
            if (platformFeatureDetector.isRunningOnAndroid()) {
                beanAccess = BeanAccess.FIELD;
            }
        }
    
        protected Map<String, Property> getPropertiesMap(Class<?> type, BeanAccess bAccess) {
            if (propertiesCache.containsKey(type)) {
                return propertiesCache.get(type);
            }
    
            Map<String, Property> properties = new LinkedHashMap<String, Property>();
            boolean inaccessableFieldsExist = false;
            switch (bAccess) {
                case FIELD:
                    for (Class<?> c = type; c != null; c = c.getSuperclass()) {
                        for (Field field : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
                            int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
                            if (!Modifier.isStatic(modifiers) && !Modifier.isTransient(modifiers)
                                    && !properties.containsKey(field.getName())) {
                                properties.put(field.getName(), new FieldProperty(field));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    // add JavaBean properties
                    try {
                        for (PropertyDescriptor property : Introspector.getBeanInfo(type)
                                .getPropertyDescriptors()) {
                            Method readMethod = property.getReadMethod();
                            if ((readMethod == null || !readMethod.getName().equals("getClass"))
                                    && !isTransient(property)) {
                                properties.put(property.getName(), new MethodProperty(property));
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
                        throw new YAMLException(e);
                    }
    
                    // add public fields
                    for (Class<?> c = type; c != null; c = c.getSuperclass()) {
                        for (Field field : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
                            int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
                            if (!Modifier.isStatic(modifiers) && !Modifier.isTransient(modifiers)) {
                                if (Modifier.isPublic(modifiers)) {
                                    properties.put(field.getName(), new FieldProperty(field));
                                } else {
                                    inaccessableFieldsExist = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            if (properties.isEmpty() && inaccessableFieldsExist) {
                throw new YAMLException("No JavaBean properties found in " + type.getName());
            }
            System.out.println(properties);
            propertiesCache.put(type, properties);
            return properties;
        }
    
        private static final String TRANSIENT = "transient";
    
        private boolean isTransient(FeatureDescriptor fd) {
            return Boolean.TRUE.equals(fd.getValue(TRANSIENT));
        }
    
        public Set<Property> getProperties(Class<? extends Object> type) {
            return getProperties(type, beanAccess);
        }
    
        public Set<Property> getProperties(Class<? extends Object> type, BeanAccess bAccess) {
            if (readableProperties.containsKey(type)) {
                return readableProperties.get(type);
            }
            Set<Property> properties = createPropertySet(type, bAccess);
            readableProperties.put(type, properties);
            return properties;
        }
    
        protected Set<Property> createPropertySet(Class<? extends Object> type, BeanAccess bAccess) {
            Set<Property> properties = new LinkedHashSet<>();
            Collection<Property> props = getPropertiesMap(type, bAccess).values();
            for (Property property : props) {
                if (property.isReadable() && (allowReadOnlyProperties || property.isWritable())) {
                    properties.add(property);
                }
            }
            return properties;
        }
    
        public Property getProperty(Class<? extends Object> type, String name) {
            return getProperty(type, name, beanAccess);
        }
    
        public Property getProperty(Class<? extends Object> type, String name, BeanAccess bAccess) {
            Map<String, Property> properties = getPropertiesMap(type, bAccess);
            Property property = properties.get(name);
            if (property == null && skipMissingProperties) {
                property = new MissingProperty(name);
            }
            if (property == null) {
                throw new YAMLException(
                        "Unable to find property '" + name + "' on class: " + type.getName());
            }
            return property;
        }
    
        public void setBeanAccess(BeanAccess beanAccess) {
            if (platformFeatureDetector.isRunningOnAndroid() && beanAccess != BeanAccess.FIELD) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "JVM is Android - only BeanAccess.FIELD is available");
            }
    
            if (this.beanAccess != beanAccess) {
                this.beanAccess = beanAccess;
                propertiesCache.clear();
                readableProperties.clear();
            }
        }
    
        public void setAllowReadOnlyProperties(boolean allowReadOnlyProperties) {
            if (this.allowReadOnlyProperties != allowReadOnlyProperties) {
                this.allowReadOnlyProperties = allowReadOnlyProperties;
                readableProperties.clear();
            }
        }
    
        public boolean isAllowReadOnlyProperties() {
            return allowReadOnlyProperties;
        }
    
        /**
         * Skip properties that are missing during deserialization of YAML to a Java
         * object. The default is false.
         *
         * @param skipMissingProperties
         *            true if missing properties should be skipped, false otherwise.
         */
        public void setSkipMissingProperties(boolean skipMissingProperties) {
            if (this.skipMissingProperties != skipMissingProperties) {
                this.skipMissingProperties = skipMissingProperties;
                readableProperties.clear();
            }
        }
    
        public boolean isSkipMissingProperties() {
            return skipMissingProperties;
        }
    }
```

Then, create your `Yaml` instance like this:

```java
        DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
        CustomPropertyUtils customPropertyUtils = new CustomPropertyUtils();
        Representer customRepresenter = new Representer();
        customRepresenter.setPropertyUtils(customPropertyUtils);
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(customRepresenter, options);
```

Profit!

Comment: Oh crikey 8[ 8[

Answer (score 4):

The keeping of property order depends on java implementation and is not guaranteed.
In order to control the yaml generation you will need to implement your `CustomRepresenter` overriding the `getProperties` , see the example below:

```java
package io.github.rockitconsulting.test.rockitizer.configuration;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.DumperOptions;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.introspector.Property;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer;



/**
 * Custom implementation of {@link Representer} and {@link Comparator} 
 * to keep the needed order of javabean properties of model classes, 
 * thus generating the understandable yaml  
 *
 */
public class ConfigurationModelRepresenter extends Representer {

    
    public ConfigurationModelRepresenter() {
        super();
    }

    public ConfigurationModelRepresenter(DumperOptions options) {
        super(options);
        
    }

    
    protected Set<Property> getProperties(Class<? extends Object> type) {
        Set<Property> propertySet;
        if (typeDefinitions.containsKey(type)) {
            propertySet = typeDefinitions.get(type).getProperties();
        }
        
        propertySet =  getPropertyUtils().getProperties(type);
        
        List<Property> propsList = new ArrayList<>(propertySet);
        Collections.sort(propsList, new BeanPropertyComparator());
        
        return new LinkedHashSet<>(propsList);
    }

    
    class BeanPropertyComparator implements Comparator<Property> {
        public int compare(Property p1, Property p2) {
            
            if (p1.getType().getCanonicalName().contains("util") && !p2.getType().getCanonicalName().contains("util")) {
                return 1;
            } else if(p2.getName().endsWith("Name")|| p2.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            } // returning 0 would merge keys
        }
    }
}
```

The below snippet shows the usage of the newly created class to generate the yaml structure:

```java
DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
ConfigurationModelRepresenter customRepresenter = new ConfigurationModelRepresenter();
        
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(customRepresenter, options);
        
        
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
yaml.dump(suite, writer);

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(rootPathTestSrc + "config_gen.yml", false);
fw.write(writer.toString());
fw.close();
```

This approach is much cleaner, comparing to the one suggested above.